# JSONException when parsing the the json string: no value for

Tags: android, json

Hi i am trying to parse a json string ,but getting jsonexception: no value found for product, i am taking product as jsonobject below is my json code

```
{
    "Product": {
        "Budget": {
            "Value": {
                "Cake": 200,
                "butter": 757993,
                "Gelsd": 404130,
                "Yeast": 404130,
                "Yeas": 43379276,
                "Gels": 1777776,

            },
            "Vol": {
                "Cake": 27899,
                "butter": 1266,
                "Gelsd": 2032,
                "Yeast":404130,
                "Yeas": 985721,
                "Gels": 16563,
  }}}}
```

I am doing as below:

```
try {
     JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(text);
     JSONObject productObject = mainObject.getJSONObject("product");
     JSONObject  attributeObject = productObject.getJSONObject(ATTRIBUTES1);
     JSONObject valueObject = attributeObject.getJSONObject(PRODUCT_VALUE);
     JSONObject volumeObject = attributeObject.getJSONObject(PRODUCT_VOLUME);

     String  cake = valueObject.getString(PRODUCT_CAKE);
     String  butter = valueObject.getString(PRODUCT_BUTTER);
     String  gelsd = valueObject.getString(PRODUCT_GELSD);
     String  yeast = valueObject.getString(PRODUCT_YEAST);
     String  yeas = valueObject.getString(PRODUCT_YEAS);

     System.out.println("cake============="+cake);
     System.out.println("butter============="+butter);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Am i parsing the right way?

Comment: Your json is invalid. Checke here http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: @BirajZalavadia the formater says its valid...

Comment: Thanks all ,yeahh i have missed the capitals...

Answer (score 1):

You have this

```
   "Product": {   // P is caps but you have p
```

Change this

```
  JSONObject productObject = mainObject.getJSONObject("product");
```

TO

```
  JSONObject productObject = mainObject.getJSONObject("Product");
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to check by

```
JSONObject productObject = mainObject.getJSONObject("product");
```

but in your json data it is **Product**

so change

```
JSONObject productObject = mainObject.getJSONObject("Product");
```

Answer (score 1):

Mis-spelled array 'product' instead of 'Product'

```
JSONObject productObject = mainObject.getJSONObject("Product");
```

Also use gson library to parse Json Data.
see example

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

You change your json object creation , use "Product" instead of "product"

Use

```
JSONObject productObject = mainObject.getJSONObject("Product");
```

instead of

```
JSONObject productObject = mainObject.getJSONObject("product");
```